# Can't to unfocused mouse from list when move keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I can't disable focus element on list where mouseenter, i wan't focus follow mouse or keypress down or up.

I'm tried function unbid("mouseenter") when we press button but that unfortunately not work.

I'm tried run this code on fiddle but this not work sorry.

I have fallowing html

```
<input id="text" type="text" />
   <div class="dropdown dropdown-tip">
     <div class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></div>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1"></ul>
  </div>
```

jQuery code

```
         var data = ['asdf',
        "asdw", "wequiye", "sagdsaj", "weoqiu"];

        $("#text").on("input", function(e){
            var a = "";
               $.each(data, function(index, value){
                 a +="<li class='sd'><a href='#'>" + value + "</a></li>";
               });
            $('.dropdown-menu').empty().append(a);
            $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown("toggle");
        });

            $("#text").on("click", function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });

        $('.dropdown-menu').on("keydown mouseenter", "li", function(e){
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if(code == 40) {
                $(this).find("a").focus();
            }else if (code == 38) {
                $(this).find("a").focus();
            }
           else if(e.type == "mouseenter") {
                $(this).find("a").focus();
            }

        });

        $("#text").keydown(function( e ){
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
            if(code == 40) {
                $('.dropdown-menu').find("li:first-child > a").focus();
            }
        });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/1354/

Comment: So why not set it up in a fiddle so we can test it, we have no way of knowing what `dropdown()` is supposed to do ?

Comment: fiddle added to test